@solana/spl-token splDiscriminate.ts _stream_writable.js:57 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
A few hrs ago I started receiving the following message that goes away when I comment out the line that imports the @solana/spl-token:
_stream_writable.js:57 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
    at node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js (_stream_writable.js:57:81)
    at __require2 (chunk-MXXBJFJ4.js?v=1532b7aa:27:50)
    at node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (readable-browser.js:4:20)
    at __require2 (chunk-MXXBJFJ4.js?v=1532b7aa:27:50)
    at node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/index.js (index.js:5:14)
    at __require2 (chunk-MXXBJFJ4.js?v=1532b7aa:27:50)
    at node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js (index.js:39:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-MXXBJFJ4.js?v=1532b7aa:27:50)
    at splDiscriminate.ts:1:28

Version  "@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.6",
It was installed already and working, then started throwing this error a while a ago.
Update: Downgrading to version "  "@solana/spl-token": "^0.1.8"," makes the problem gow away and the page loads, but that version doesn't export the functionality I was testing from the guides. e.g. getAssociatedTokenAddressSync

Update/Temporary Solution:
In Chrome, I was getting a more specific error:

Following the provided links I was able to put a breakpoint in the line 11378 (1st link in the error trace) and noticed the browser and version where always undefined, but the process contained information ab out my local environment and vite config.



Then, I searched for several process.browser in each of the files 9 search in folder ) and found this usage:

Solution
Then, on vite.config.js

    define: {
        "process.env": process.env,
        //"process.env.version" : '3.5',
        "process.browser": true,
        // // By default, Vite doesn't include shims for NodeJS/
        // // necessary for segment analytics lib to work
        //"Buffer": Buffer,
        global: {},
    },


